# Rails : serialize Ruby range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, yaml, rails-activerecord

I'm running Rails 3.2.17 (also tried it with 3.2.22).
I have trouble with serialization of a ruby Range in my model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :my_column
  serialize :my_column, Range
end
```

When I try to create an record like this:

```
MyModel.create()
# Or like this
MyModel.create({my_column: (0..2)})
```

I have this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
```

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

I have found a way like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :my_column
  # NO MORE SERIALIZE

  def my_column=(val)
    self[:my_column] = YAML.dump(val)
  end

  def my_column
    YAML.load(super || YAML.dump(nil))
  end
end
```

Comment: JFYI, parentheses are not a part of syntax for ranges. Can be just `MyModel.create(my_column: 0..2)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : indeed, I just have this habit of putting them for readability.

Comment: Yep, won't hurt. :)